# How to put Html lines on matrix 2d java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, 2d

So my Question is how can I put this HTML in a matrix 2d

```
enter code here   <TR>
                <TD>Mikel</TD>
                <TD>---</TD>
                <TD>1</TD>
                <TD>1</TD>
                <TD>1</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>John</TD>
                <TD>1</TD>
                <TD>---</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>X-Men</TD>
                <TD>1</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>---</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>Dimitri</TD>
                <TD>1</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>---</TD>
                <TD>1</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>1</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
```

Like this

```
    Mikel       John    X-Men   Dimitri
```

Mikel    ---          1        1    1
John      1         ---        0    0
X-Men     1         0        ---    0
Dimitri   1         0         0     ---

while (fInput.hasNextLine()) {
            str = fInput.nextLine().trim();

```
         String[] temp = str.split(" ");
         Matriz [cont][cont] = temp [0].trim();
```

Comment: Do you have any mechanism for parsin HTML or XML available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This HTML is also an XML with each TR as one row of the 2D matrix
You can use DOM/SAX parsing ,parse all the TR tags adding the value of the first TD element in the first row of the matrix and value of all elements in TR can be added as individual rows thereafter.

Comment: You can use regex based parsing on each line of that file.